# Bitshift Causing Overflow When It Shouldn't

Tags: c, linux, bit-shift

When I am bitshifting the max positive 2's complement, shouldn't shifting it 31 bits make an effective 0 because it starts as 0111 1111, etc.

I have tried decreasing the shift but I am assuming it's just the computer reading it incorrectly.

```
int main(void) 
{
  int x = 0x7FFFFFFF;
  int nx = ~x;
  int ob = nx >> 31;
  int ans = ob & nx;

  printf("%d",ans);
}
```

I am expecting ob to be 0 but it turns out as the twos complement minimum. I am using this to create a bang without actually using !.

Comment: It is implementation-defined behavior whether or not the sign-bit shifts for signed numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were shifting the max positive two's complement number, it *would* end up as zero.

But you are *not* shifting that number:

```
int x = 0x7FFFFFFF;
int nx = ~x;          // 0x80000000 (assuming 32-bit int).
```

You are bit-shifting the largest (in magnitude) *negative* number.

And, as per the standards document `C11 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators /5` (my emphasis):

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1 / 2^E2` . ***If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.***

Your implementation seems to preserve the sign bit, which is why you end up with the non-zero negative value.

---

As an aside, if you want a `!` operator, you can just use:

```
output = (input == 0);
```

See afore-mentioned standard, `6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators /5` (again, my emphasis) where it explicitly calls out the equivalence:

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is `0` if the value of its operand compares unequal to `0`, `1` if the value of its operand compares equal to `0`. The result has type `int`. ***The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.***

Comment: Of course, thank you. However, one more question, why does ob come out to -1 (as per my tests) when we shift 0x80000000 31 bits to the right?

Comment: @KennethStraw: if you're getting `-1`, your implementation both preserves the sign bit *and* shifts it into the leftmost magnitude bit. Hence you see `0x80000000`, `0xc0000000`, `0xe0000000`, `0xf0000000`, `0xf8000000`, `0xfc000000`, all the way to `0xffffffff`.

Comment: Thank you so much that clears a lot up, and as for the ! operator I am only allowed to use ~ & ^ | + << and >> operators. Still, thank you so much!